# Getting all the children of an element that are textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of text areas that are children of a div that has an id. I want to get the text in each of those text areas in an array - so is there a way in jquery to get all the children that are of a certain type(in this case text area) of a certain parent?

I've tried this -

```
$("#optionGroup_0").children('input[type=text], textarea');
```

but that returns an empty array. I think the above method would work if I had the right selector for a text area, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `.find()` is every descendant, where `.children()` goes only one level deep.  See:  http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
var array = $("#optionGroup_0 textarea").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/e424b/1)

Comment: In that case your textarea are not direct children, I've updated my code to reflect that, please check it out again.

Comment: ah this is perfect- achieves not only want, but what I wanted it for! thanks!

Comment: I'm glad this resolved your problem, please consider upvoting if this was helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` is every descendant, where `.children()` goes only one level deep. See: [api.jquery.com/find](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
$("#optionGroup_0").find('input[type=text], textarea');
```

Comment: thanks- do I need to go through the resulting array again to get the value of each one?

Comment: Yes, I'm simply showing how to more properly get your target elements.

Comment: thanks for this - I didn't know children was only one level deep - I'll up vote you anyways, even if I've accepted Nelson's answer.

Comment: @praks5432: Thanks.  I agree that Nelson's answer is best, but you're still welcome to up/down vote any other answer you wish.